# What do I do if I my (Drupal 7) content types do not require a title?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

What do I do if I my (Drupal 7) content types do not require a title?

They are not articles or blog entires or news articles etc, they are data. There is no title.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can entirely remove the title from the nodes but you may hide it and automatically populate it, using the modules "Auto node titles" and "Title override".

Answer (score 1):

chick this out , may be it ll help
http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete "title" field. This field is built in node module.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new entity type. Your new entity type does not have to have a title. Look here to learn how to create an entity: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7

Answer (score -1):

put none betwenn <> in the title of the post.